# Firestore transaction doesn't fail when I delete a document

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, transactions

I want to assign a wallet to a user and then delete the wallet so it won't be assigned again to another user. I'm using transactions for this, but the transaction resumes without throwing even if I manually delete the document:

```
try {
  return await admin.firestore().runTransaction(async t => {
    // get the user document (users collection)
    const userSnapshot = await t.get(userRef);
    const user = userSnapshot.data();

    // if it has a wallet, just return it
    if (user.wallet) return user.wallet;

    // now I get a wallet (wallets collection, id was randomically picked)
    const walletShapshot = await t.get(walletRef);
    // if wallet was deleted by another execution, return undefined (it'll be retried by the code that started the transaction)
    if (!walletShapshot.exists) return;

    console.log('before', wallet.id, wallet.address);
    await delay(20000); // <== here I manually delete the document from firestore
    console.log('moving on')

    const w = await walletShapshot.data();
    console.log('after', walletShapshot.id, w.address);

    await t.delete(walletRef); // here it's deleting the already deleted wallet

    await t.update(userRef, {
      wallet: w.address,
      walletReferenceId: w.referenceId,
      assigned: new Date().toISOString()
    });

    return w.address; // here I get the wallet that was deleted!
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
  // returning undefined will trigger a retry
}
```

The docs state that deletes are considered changes to the underlying document, so transactions will revert, but instead I get the wallet that was deleted during the transaction.

What's the problem here?

Edit:
Here's what the docs say about `.delete()` in transactions:

> A transaction consists of any number of get() operations followed by
> any number of write operations such as set(), update(), or delete().
> In the case of a concurrent edit, Cloud Firestore runs the entire
> transaction again. For example, if a transaction reads documents and
> another client modifies any of those documents, Cloud Firestore
> retries the transaction. This feature ensures that the transaction
> runs on up-to-date and consistent data.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions

Comment: Could you link and cite the specific documentation that suggests the behavior you're seeing is incorrect?  Note that deleting a document normally does not yield an error if was not present.

Comment: Sure thing, added the reference to the question @DougStevenson

Comment: What if you delete the document not in the console, but in another program that uses a transaction to delete it?  It might be that "concurrent edit" only applies to multiple clients each using a transaction. After all, the whole point of transactions is for clients to agree with each other on the atomicity of operations so they don't clobber each other.  Clobbering is very much a reality outside of transactions.

Comment: You're right. I'll post an answer to explain a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Firestore uses two concurrency models: for client SDKs it uses optimistic control and for admin SDKs, pessimistic control.

This means on the back-end it'll put sequential transactions on hold and execute them as soon as the lock is released.

It looks like my test was wrong, as per Doug Steverson's suggestion. Transaction isolation will happen in the same context the transaction has been started:

> It might be that "concurrent edit" only applies to multiple clients each using a transaction.

I confirm that two edits to the same document, in the same context, are queued and resolved without errors.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/transaction-data-contention#isolation_within_a_transaction